# How do I add static items in drop down list in Excel using VBScript

Tags: excel, vbscript

Using VBScript to control an Excel workbook, I am able to add 1 item to the drop-down list. However, I am not sure how to further add more items. This is my code:

```
Set excelAppObj = CreateObject("excel.appliction")
Set workbookObj = excelAppObj.Workbooks.Add
Set worksheetObj = workbookObj.Sheets(1)
With worksheetObj.Range("A1").Validation
    .Add 3, 1, 1, "test1"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropDown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to add a drop down list in excel using vbs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21788845/how-to-add-a-drop-down-list-in-excel-using-vbs)

Comment: @user692942 I have read up on that post, but that posts adds in multiple items based on a range of items in the excel workbook. For my case, I would just like a static list with "Acceptable" or "Ignore" and I do not know how to add the 2 options.

Comment: @user692942 so in order to place the items in the drop down list, I will need to place them somewhere on the worksheet?

Comment: If you just want a static list, you should be able to specify the values you want in the formula as a delimited list. Try removing `"test1"` and replacing it with `"Acceptable,Ignore"` that way no cell range is required.

Comment: Relevant - [How to create a Named Constant Array for Use in Data Validation?](https://superuser.com/a/1045145)